# How to access Gmail for storage in custom CRM using a SQL Server database?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, gmail, crm

I have a client who wants his custom-written CRM to be able to access his sales people's emails so that, effectively, a history of email conversations between customer and salesperson is stored inside the CRM's database.

The CRM is written in [Visual Basic 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET#2008_.28VB_9.0.29) and the database is [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008). The only email these people use, in the shop and on the road, is [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail). Each sales person has their own Gmail address. That's how they operate.

If they're on the road and respond to a customer's email inquiry about a product, they would like that email conversation to be stored in a table in the database. I think that's the part I can't wrap my head around. How do I get access to the email data (knowing the user id and password) and doing so from Visual Basic 2008?

A free or close to free solution would be preferred.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Access Gmail (SSL enabled) using SMTP, IMAP and POP3 protocols : Retrieve messages from the mailbox](http://www.theserverside.net/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=48505)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that we have done in the past is create a separate email account and just have the users to BCC this email address, for example, crm@somewhere.com. We then have a small application, on the server, that polls email from this central mailbox and automatically attaches it to the entity based on the recipients email address.

We also allow the user to add some commands at the bottom of the email, for attaching to things like work orders and/or bills, for example, wo 1000 (for a work order 1000) or b 1000 (for bill 1000).

Just another idea.

Comment: Thanks!  I will run that past them.  Of course, thats asking the sales people to remember to perform another step. :O   How, though, did you access the GMAIL content (to:, from:, subject:, body: and attachments, etc)?   Did you use IMAP or SMTP/POP3 and if so, was there a library of functions you wrote or purchased (or free if possible)..  Its one of those clients that says "if it costs too much I dont want it and if takes too long then forget it".  Ugh.

Comment: We used the MailBee components http://www.afterlogic.com/, they were a little pricey but they allowed us to get the solution up and running quickly ... the other way we did was through the Outlook object model running on as server, not very reliable ... but worked without any additional costs.

Comment: Thank you.  I dont have time to write that stuff from scratch so the client (hopefully) will understand that.  Time IS money.  I am still seeking cheaper or free/open solutions however.